# What is the best way to show that the exponential sequence doesn't uniformally converge on an unbounded interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say we use the usual definition of $$E_n(x)=1+x+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I know that on any bounded interval it converges uniformly, I am trying to show that it does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

I know that uniform convergence maintains boundedness so I am thinking it will definitely have to do with that, but I am just not sure the best way to show it without using things like convergence of series.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $E_n(x)$ converges to $e^x$ for any $x$.

If you choose any $\epsilon>0$ and any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then for any $x>0$,

$$|E_n(x)-e^x|=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\cdots$$

This clearly increases without bound as $x\to+\infty$ since each term increases in that way. We can therefore choose an $x\in[0,+\infty)$ such that

$$|E_n(x)-e^x|>\epsilon$$

Since we find such an $x\in[0,+\infty)$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, this contradicts [the definition of uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition) on that interval.

Answer (score 0):

That's because if it were uniformly convergent, it would converge to $e^x$. But now, for all $n$
$$\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \left| e^x - \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \right) \right| \ge \lim_{x \to \infty} \left| e^x - \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \right) \right| = +\infty$$
and this does not approach to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks but how would you prove the limit?

Comment: Taylor polynomial error term estimates would suffice, I think